# Interpreting Keras Loss and Accuracy graphs

Tags: performance, keras, neural-network

I am having some trouble interpreting these loss and accuracy graphs.
For instance, in the first one, the validation loss value is rather low (it already starts below 0.35), but it then diverges rapidly.
On the other hand, in the second one, the validation starts at a higher value and then it seems to reach a plateau (it does not start growing as in the first case).
Also, the fourth graph seems somewhat strange, as both validation loss and validation accuracy seem to decrease over the epochs.

Which of these four graph would you consider to be the best one?

Thank you in advance,
Andrea
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Which of these four graph would you consider to be the best one?

This is the wrong question to ask, as you are not taking into account test (or unseen data) in your analysis.

In the first graph, note that the validation loss is increasing while the training loss is decreasing. This indicates that your model suffers from **overfitting** - a situation where your model will predict the training data with high accuracy but not the validation data.

In terms of which graphs are "better", one cannot tell simply by assessing the graphs alone.

I'm not sure if you have already done this, but the true test as to whether your neural network functions properly is whether the model is adept at predicting **test data**, i.e. new data that is unseen by the model.

You could find that the model performs well in predicting the training and validation data - and therefore the loss curves continue to show a downward sloping pattern as the loss decreases, but this tells you nothing about how the model will perform on the test data.

In this regard, you should check which configuration performs best on unseen data - assessing solely by the shape of the curves is erroneous if you have not considered the accuracy of the predictions on new data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I get your point.
Nevertheless, validation loss and accuracy are estimated through cross-validation, shouldn't it approximate the behaviour of the net on unseen data?

Comment: Well, if the unseen data is in any way included in the model when training (either training or val data) then it will skew the results - otherwise known as data leakage.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the reason behind the strange relationship between loss and accuracy in the graphs.

The fact is that the validation scores are established through 4-fold cross-validation; thus, 4 models are learnt and their results are averaged.

However, I thought that Keras' model.fit() would reset the weights in the models, which in fact it does not. So, I have now added a line to redefine the model inside each fold, to ensure that the learning start from scratch each time.

Now I am getting much more sensible graphs, for instance:

[image]